# Is there a way in jquery or javascript to populate dropdown lists on page load without using an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to populate a few dropdown lists using jQuery when the page loads, rather than using ajax responding to an event, which I have currently and is working.
My Controller builds up several List objects for these dropdowns.
Currently I use ajax and my actions return the data, but this needs to be in my view when it renders.

C# code:

```
    return Json(ddlVals1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

    return Json(ddlValAnother, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Example of what I wish to do in my jQuery Code;

```
$(function ()
{
    LoadUserDropDown();
    LoadAnotherDropDown();
});
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is possible as long as you pass the list values to view. For example, you can use ViewBag to transfer temporary data to View.

```
// Action
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.FirstDropDownList = new List<string>() { "Item 1", "Item 2" };
    ViewBag.FirstDropDownListJson = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewBag.FirstDropDownList);
    return View("Index");
}

// View using razor
<select>
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.FirstDropDownList) 
{
    <option value="@item">@item</option>
}
</select>

// View using jQuery
<select id="dropdown1"></select>
<script>
    $(function(){
        var dropdown1List = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.FirstDropDownListJson)');
        $('#dropdown1').html($.map(dropdown1List, a => `<option value="${a}">${a}</option>`));
    });
</script>
```